# How to react to a code pair reviewer pointing out way too many small details

Tags: code-reviews

I recently came to a situation where I could not really figure out how to react. During a project, in a paired code review, the software architecte began pointing out even the smallest detail of my code before aproving the PR, even when production day is really really close. It would seem fair, if not for the fact that when I went to the data collected by SonarQube, he has more than 160 bad practices detected, and I have only 7, of which, 4 are TODOs because fonctional spec are not ready. 
So, I could really need help knowing how to react. Does it makes sense to correct the smallest detail in my code, or should I engage in a philosophical argument pointing out that his annotations are a waste of time given the close timetable on our hands ?

Juste to point out, we need the code to be merged because we need feedback from the clients in order to proceed with the code in TODO.

Comment: I'll leave a comment as this is opinionated; Do what he says but point out that bigger issues need to be addressed and suggest that you do the cleanup if and when you're done with critical functionality. That's only if the things are truly trivial. Judging by your post you're "outranked" in the hierarchy so you can't really be held liable (or, well, shouldn't) if you miss the deadline.

Comment: If he doesn't point them out now, when should he? Because your immediate reply would be: "why is this now a problem? When last week you were ok with it." Damned if you do, damned if you don't.

Comment: This is a bit too broad to go into, but waiving code thru because the deadline is approaching is a false economy...

Comment: Small details can kill companies and people. Don't think you know better just because you spend your time doing what a static code analyzer tells you to do. If you don't have time to fix it all ask for priorities.

Answer (score 4):

> Does it makes sense to correct the smallest detail in my code [?]

What precisely is the *smallest* detail? There is no objective measure of size, nor a degree to where you have the superlative "smallest possible detail". You're manipulating your words to change perception of the issue, though I cannot say whether this is intentional or subconscious.

This entire question is grasping at straws for any reason (valid or not) for not fixing something that you don't even disagree is an actual issue. Nothing in this question argues against the flaws being pointed out being incorrect.

---

> the software architect began pointing out even the smallest detail of my code before aproving the PR, even when production day is really really close
>
> ... should I engage in a philosophical argument pointing out that his annotations are a waste of time given the close timetable on our hands ?

If the deadline decides the standard of code quality that should be reviewed, then there are severe misconceptions at play here about the purpose of code quality and reviewing it.

This is a red flag for you either not understanding or outright dismissing clean coding practices.

---

> It would seem fair, if not for the fact that when I went to the data collected by SonarQube, he has more than 160 bad practices detected, and I have only 7, of which, 4 are TODOs because fonctional spec are not ready.

That is the [fallacy of relative privation](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Not_as_bad_as), also known as the "not as bad as" fallacy; though in this case you are pushing it into [ad hominem](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_hominem) territory.

Someone having made mistakes of their own does not somehow invalidate their point about a completely different subject.

Secondly, quantifying the alleged mistakes is pointless as it deprives the argument of reasonable context, such as hours worked, seniority, ...
Assuming similarly sized change requests for the sake of example, a developer who tackles one flawed CR a week does not somehow become "better" than a developer who pushes out multiple CRs a week, with more than one being flawed.

Let's assume for a second that the reviewer is being hypocritical and in fact makes the same mistakes that he's pointing out in your code. That just means that you **both** have things to fix. Nothing about this somehow invalidates the fact that you still have to fix your code.

What the basis for your argument here? If there's *any* mistake, then all bets are off for code quality reviews?
Well, in that case, I don't think the police should be fining me for speeding while there's still a bank robber at large - because that is clearly a more pressing matter, no?

---

> I have only 7, of which, 4 are TODOs because fonctional spec are not ready

Agreeing that something is a flaw is not the same as agreeing you need to immediately fix it. If something is known to be a TODO or WIP, then it shouldn't even be reviewed yet.

*However:*

> before aproving the PR

When you open a pull request, you are stating that the code is finished, yet you just stated that it's still a TODO and you don't even have the spec yet.

Why on Earth would you try to put unfavorably reviewed code *that isn't even finished yet* to the source branch?

---

> I have only 7 [bad practices], of which, 4 are TODOs because fonctional spec are not ready

If you're waiting for the spec anyway, that clearly means you are able to look at things that are actually fixable. While the 4 TODOs are awaiting further information from the analysts, that gives you time to address the other 3 issues.

---

And lastly, Pieter B's comment deserves a bigger spotlight:

> If he doesn't point them out now, when should he? Because your immediate reply would be: "why is this now a problem? When last week you were ok with it." Damned if you do, damned if you don't.

When exactly would be an appropriate time for you to fix the flaws in your code? After the pull request is merged? After a production release? When you don't have other duties to attend to? Whenever there is work time but no work?

You're trying to dodge having to fix your code without any practical argument as to why or when it will actually be addressed should it not be done right away (which it should be).

Comment: This is all defensible except the part that suggests the amount of time you have to review and fix even the smallest stylistic problems is unlimited.  It isn't.

Comment: Ok, maybe I was a little too broad. I was pointed out details of type "Sort your usings before commiting". Again, this would seem reasonable, if not for the fact that we are wating for the feedback of already developed fonctionnalities to proceed with the rest of the TODOs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Of course time isn't unlimited, but that doesn't invalidate the review process itself. It's perfectly acceptable to let slip some small and inconsequential problems, as long as your either (a) accept and document them or (b) genuinely commit to fix them at a later stage.

Comment: @AlfredoA.: You repeatedly argue that you both "don't have time" and "are waiting for other feedback". Those are contradictions. You're trying to have your cake and eat it - both argument are only being used when they benefit your position.

Comment: I'm not in his environment, so I don't know who is the reasonable one, but there is such a thing as bikeshedding in code reviews.

Comment: @Flater, no, it doesn't. I'm all in for code review. I am just not so in for the part where an architect takes hours to code review my code to point out that my usings are not properly sorted, while the needed feedback to proceed is being delayed, and also, in his own code, he has way more serious problems.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I don't disagree, but I don't think it applies in this scenario where OP tries to push unfavorably reviewed and incomplete code for a deadline (which I surmise is a production release). You are objectively right but I fear that opening that door in this context ends up providing the incentive for continuing down the wrong path.

Comment: It should be noted that the review was *approved*. YMMV but for me, that gives carte blanche for the developer to attend to the issues or leave them to later iterations.

Comment: @AlfredoA, I recently had a code review where the architect essentially asked me to bring a bunch of files in compliance with the coding standard, while I only added a small feature and keeping it in the same style as the rest of the file. That same architect had earlier accepted the same code when it was received from an external company. Sometimes you just have to swallow your pride and get on with it.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau And sometimes you have to push back when there are more pressing priorities...